# Get child view inside a Listview Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Inside my getView method I want to get a specific child view. I know that my adapter holds several items, by doing calling getCount:

```
getCount();
```

According to the JavaDoc:

```
public abstract int getCount () 
Added in API level 1
How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
```

Now in my getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View lastAddedItem = parent.getChildAt(getCount()-1);
   if(lastAddedItem == null)  {
     Log.w("ListAdapter", "View is null");
   }

}
```

This message always appears in the `LogCat`, which means that the View I try to grab is `Null`.

I've also tried this:

```
View lastAddedItem = parent.getChildAt(parent.getChildCount()-1);
```

So how can I grab a specific view from my `ViewGroup` object?

Comment: you don't wana do this ... belive me ... what's you wanna achieve?

Comment: I just want to animate a specific `View` in my `ViewGroup`. Why is this bad pratice? I'm just making a copy of the view and do operations on this copy.

Comment: IFAIK, it will always give you null.. because listview behavior is to recycle the views. so your view isn't drawn on the screen, so it is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that my adapter holds several items, by doing calling
>   getCount:

Yes it does, but the `getCount()`(returning the items **in the Adapter**) method of an adapter has nothing to do with getting the children of a `ListView` with `getChildAt()`(where you should use `getChildCount()` as this will return the `Views` **present in the `ViewGroup`**).

> lastAddedItem = parent.getChildAt(parent.getChildCount()-1);

This should return a non-null view, the last view returned by the `getView()` method.

> I just want to animate a specific View in my ViewGroup

If you are going to animate a list row(or part of that row) when it becomes visible than register a scroll listener for the `ListView` and start the animation from there when the target view is appearing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how are you implemented the rest of the adapter, but if you are doing it in the right way, and I am right, the parent only contains the Views being displayed on the device's screen, and each time you pull down or pull up the list, it modifies the content of those views, that is why you get Null.

What you want to achieve (animate a view), should be done in runtime, checking if the view currently being displayed in the screen should be animated or not.

Hope it helps.